# CakePHP 2.0 CakeLog limit log size

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How do I limit the log size when using CakeLog? I am using Ubuntu, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `logrotate`, which is included in Ubuntu. Create a file in `/etc/logrotate.d` named something like `cakelogs`. An example which would rotate and compress all *.log files in all Cake tmp/logs directories would look like this:

```
/var/www/*/public/tmp/logs/*.log {
    weekly
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    dateext
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 www-data www-data
    sharedscripts
}
```